# How to get wishlist product category ID.?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, wishlist

I was assign one product in more then one category.

In one of , i was added product in Wishlist .

I want to know that this product is come for which category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Magento Wishlist models** does ***not contain the category details at it's tables***. So you need customization for your requirement and in this case you need to  use `core/session` or `catalog/session` model to store data in session.

Maybe `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLastVisitedCategoryId()` is an alternative solution for your case. I am not sure 100% about it.